# Is it possible to import a module in python, then delete it, but still be able to use it within program?

Tags: python, module

Is it possible to do the following in Python?

Pseudo-code:

```
<code to extract contents from a password-protected .zip file (includes module)>
<path to module>
import module
reload(module)
<delete extracted contents, including the imported module>
<program code (within it, use reload(module) to use the module)>
```

The purpose of this is to basically make the module "invisible" to the user. I know that if the user really wants to get it, he can, but this is just more of a deterrent. I also know that this may not be desirable at all, but is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might work, if by "contents includes module" you mean a `.py` file, and if the first `import module` can create a `module.pyc` file (which normally it can, but for example a read-only filesystem would stop it). If you don't delete that `.pyc` file, then `reload(module)` can load from it.

If there's another `module.py` found later in the include path, then deleting the files from one place would result in `reload` loading it from another.

If you delete all files relating to `module` everywhere in the path then it can't be reloaded, because what reload means is, "go load this from the include path".